# Python Flask for cnn-text-classification tensorflow POST request format

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, flask, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am doing [cnn-text-classification-tf](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf).   My aim is to do prediction from frozen graph.

My question is how can the prediction be done from the frozen graph. I found a great tutorial https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc. where he is implementing frozen graph using flask.

I am using flask code like below to do prediction.

```
import json, argparse, time

import tensorflow as tf
from linkedin import load_graph

from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
##################################################
# API part
##################################################
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
@app.route("/api/predict", methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    start = time.time()

    data = request.data.decode("utf-8")
    if data == "":
        params = request.form
        x_in = json.loads(params['x'])
    else:
        params = json.loads(data)
        x_in = params['x']

    ##################################################
    # Tensorflow part
    ##################################################
    y_out = persistent_sess.run(y, feed_dict={
        x: x_in
        # x: [[3, 5, 7, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] # < 45
    })
    ##################################################
    # END Tensorflow part
    ##################################################

    json_data = json.dumps({'y': y_out.tolist()})
    print("Time spent handling the request: %f" % (time.time() - start))

    return json_data
##################################################
# END API part
##################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--frozen_model_filename", default="frozen_model2.pb", type=str, help="Frozen model file to import")
    parser.add_argument("--gpu_memory", default=.2, type=float, help="GPU memory per process")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    ##################################################
    # Tensorflow part
    ##################################################
    print('Loading the model')
    graph = load_graph(args.frozen_model_filename)
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/input_x:0')
    y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/output/predictions:0')

    print('Starting Session, setting the GPU memory usage to %f' % args.gpu_memory)
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=args.gpu_memory)
    sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
    persistent_sess = tf.Session(graph=graph, config=sess_config)
    ##################################################
    # END Tensorflow part
    ##################################################

    print('Starting the API')
    app.run()
```

I am using terminal on MacOS to run this script 
[image]

After running this I am using postman to POST the request:

[image]

How do I correctly frame this request to get proper response. What is the exact input needed in Postman in the body?

Answer (score 1):

In Postman, you are sending a POST request and data in json format, so you would need to do changes in code.

for getting data, first do the validation as follows:

```
if not 'data' in request.json:
    abort(400)
```

After that you can access the string as follows:

```
x_in = request.json["data"]
```

But in case, you want to do changes in the request then you can try sending data as follows:

```
{ 
   "data" : {
               "x" : "good movie it was"
             }
 }
```

This should work, in case not, then do let me know.

Comment: "{ 
   "data" : {
               "x" : "good movie it was"
             }
 }"This  doesn't work in postman do you need any more information I'm unsure how to debug this one

Comment: I changed  def predict():
    start = time.time()

    data = request.data.decode("utf-8")
    if not 'data' in request.json:
     abort(400)
    
    else:
        params = json.loads(data)
        x_in = request.json["data"]

Comment: Why are you passing a string? @Ajinkya Pass it without `"` commas